# SQL - Pass value to nested select query on same table without selecting the value

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I need to extract some metadata from a table which stores the keys and values, so I first choose a specific key to make a `SELECT` query, (`key_a`), then I make another query keeping the id and aiming at another data type (`key_b`), the following is a simplification of the code I have:

```
SELECT
    id AS param,
    val as key_a,
    (
        SELECT val
        FROM table
        WHERE key = 'key_b' AND id = param
    ) AS key_b

FROM table

WHERE val = 'key_a'
```

What I want is to achieve this without the `SELECT` query selecting the `id` field. Trying to remove the `id AS param,` line and replacing `param` with `id` or `table.id` have not worked so far. I am kinda lost in here since it's the first time I am working with nested queries and can't find anything regarding same table nested queries.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Don't worry, it's just a syntax question, a little naming obfuscation and absence of table description won't harm anyone. I even thought that generic names would be better for future readers, but oh well...

Comment: Except now you've gone away with the impression that that's a good (by which I mean 'efficient') way to solve this problem. So, you lose too.

Comment: Alright, to any future readers: Although the answer I accepted was the one that answered the question, most of the times, using a JOIN is by far a better performance-wise option. (SQB's answer uses JOIN).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your problem is, that you have to compare the column `id` with itself, right? Then just alias the table name instead of the column.

```
SELECT
    val as key_a,
    (
        SELECT val
        FROM table b
        WHERE key = 'key_b' AND id = a.id
    ) AS key_b
FROM table a
WHERE val = 'key_a'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed it. I didn't even know you could alias table. That's awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Use a join. If the tables are the *same* table, use a self-join.

```
SELECT
   a.val as key_a,
   b.val AS key_b
FROM table a
LEFT JOIN table b ON b.id = a.id AND b.key = 'key_b'
WHERE a.val = 'key_a'  -- perhaps you meant a.key here?
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.id as param,
  (SELECT B.val from table B where B.id = A.id and B.key = 'key_a'),
  (SELECT C.val from table C where C.id = A.id and C.key = 'key_b') 
from table A
```

I'm not sure what you want , but hope this solve your issue